# Pandas: Applying a function whilst splitting a dict into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I define a function as follows...

```
def getSentiment(x):
    vs = vaderSentiment
    col = vs(x['messages'].encode('utf-8', 'replace'))
    return col
```

The column of the DataFrame I am applying the function to contains individual strings per row (two examples)...

```
There are some classic 'Cat' ones about seatbelts
That would be the fighters steroids… I've told you
```

When I apply the function using...

```
df['sentiment']=df.apply(getSentiment, axis=1)
```

The dicts that resulted from the function are converted into string format in the new sentiment column (two rows as examples)...

```
sentiment
{'compound': 0.4404, 'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.919, 'pos': 0.081} 
{'compound': 0.4404, 'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.256, 'pos': 0.744}
```

Instead of this, is there a way to apply the function so that the key value pairs from the dict are returned as individual columns (in addition to the other variables), like this in effect:

```
compound    neg    neu      pos
0.4404      0.0    0.919    0.081
0.4404      0.0    0.256    0.744
```

Amongst other things I've tried using `DataFrame.from_dict` and searching some other answers on here but nothing seems applicable.

Comment: The original DataFrame has a column called `messages` in it. That's what function is applied to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values of column `sentiment` are **strings**, you can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) function  [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) for converting them to `dictionary`:

```
import ast

print df

#                                           sentiment  tmp
#0  {'compound': 0.4404, 'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.919,...   aa
#1  {'compound': 0.4404, 'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.256,...  sss

print type(df['sentiment'][0])

#<type 'str'>

df1 = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(ast.literal_eval(x)))
print df1

#   compound  neg    neu    pos
#0    0.4404    0  0.919  0.081
#1    0.4404    0  0.256  0.744
```

If values of column `sentiment` are **dictionaries**:

```
print df['sentiment']

#0    {u'neg': 0.0, u'neu': 0.919, u'pos': 0.081, u'...
#1    {u'neg': 0.0, u'neu': 0.256, u'pos': 0.744, u'...

print type(df['sentiment'][0])

#<type 'dict'>

print pd.DataFrame(x for x in df['sentiment'])

#   compound  neg    neu    pos
#0    0.4404    0  0.919  0.081
#1    0.4404    0  0.256  0.744
```

Comment: I cant see how this is perfect, thanks. Any idea for the error I get now: `ValueError: malformed string`!

Comment: I think string is not `key` : `value` pair, so it cannot be converted.

Comment: Is `print type(df['sentiment'][0])` string?

Comment: My mistake. `sentiment` is now a dict. I can now do `new = pd.DataFrame(x for x in df['sentiment'])` and join `new` with the original dataset. Thanks so much for persisting with this. :)